# UICollectionViewCell does load only when on view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm developing an Chat application where I have a UICollectionView to control the messages and I came to a situation I would like to confirm with you.

For exemple, let's say I have 60 items in this UICollectionView, but based on the size of the items and the scrolling options I set, only the last 10 items are visible on the screen, from 50 to 59.

Based on that, it seems I'm not able to get cellForItem at IndexPath 30, for example. Is that correct?

I would like to confirm that with you before creating a solution to go over the items that are already "on screen" and I need to check. Any ideas and solutions you have already implemented is appreciated.

Also, based on the information above if, for example, I need to move on item from index path 30 to 31, will I have problems if they are not "instantiated" in the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mixing your model, controller, and view classes, which is a bad thing™ for exactly the reason you encounter here.

I take it you're trying to access data from the index 30 (basically) and say to yourself "Hey, I already added that in the 30th cell, so I will just use the collection view's method to get that cell and take it from there". That means, you basically ask a *view* for *data*.

That won't work, because, as others pointed out (but more indirectly), *there are not 60 cells at all at any given moment*. There's basically as many cells as fit on the screen, (plus perhaps one or a few "buffer" cells so rendering during scrolling works, I can't remember that atm). This is why `cellForItem(at:)` is nil for an `IndexPath` that refers to a cell not actually visible at the moment. Basically it works in a similar way to a table view. The collection view simply does not keep around stuff it doesn't need to render for memory reasons.

If you need *anything* from a cell (which is after all also a view) at this path, why don't you get it from whatever data object represents the contents of this cell? Usually that's the `UICollectionViewDataSource`.

That's how the paradigm is supposed to work: The `UICollectionViewDataSource` is responsible for keeping around any data your app may need at a given time (this may or may not reloading it or parts of it, your choice). The `UICollectionView` uses its `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method when a certain `IndexPath` becomes visible, but it throws that away again (or rather queues it again so your data source may dequeue it in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` and reuse it for another data set that becomes visible).

And btw, please don't use use the `UICollectionViewDataSource`'s `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method to get the cell and then the data from there. This method is supposed to be called by the collection view and depending on how you reuse cells or create them, this might mess up the entire process. Or at the very least create view-related overhead. Instead, get the data in the same way your `UICollectionViewDataSource` would get in *inside* of the method. Wrap that in an additional method you rely on or the like. Or, even better, rely on the model object that the controller uses as well.

---

Edit in response to your comment:

No, I did *not* mean it's bad to use a `UIViewController` as a `UICollectionViewDataSource` for a `UICollectionView`. What I meant was that it's bad to use the **`UICollectionView`** to get **data**, *because that's what the data source is for*. In your question you were wondering why `cellForItem(at:)` gives nil. That method is defined on `UICollectionView`. You didn't mention your intention was to move items around (I'll explain in a second), so I assumed you were trying to get whatever data was in the cell (I know, "assume makes an ass out of u and me...", sorry :) ). This is not the way to go, as the `UICollectionView` is not *meant* to hold the data for you. Rather, that's your job, and you *can* use a `UICollectionViewDataSource` for that. This latter class (or rather protocol a class can adopt) is basically meant to offer an interface for `UICollectionView` to get the data. It needs that, because, as said, it doesn't keep all data around. It requests stuff it needs from the data source. The data source, on the other hand, can manage that data itself, or maybe it relies on some deeper class architecture (i.e. other objects taking care of the underlying model) to get this. That part depends on your design. For smaller scenarios having the data source simply have the data in an array or dictionary is enough. Furthermore, a lot of designs actually use a UIViewController`to adopt`UICollectionViewDataSource`. That may be sufficient, but be careful not to blow up your view controller to a monstrosity that does everything. That's just a general tip, you have to decide on your own what is "too much".

Now to your actual intention: To move around cells you don't need to get them. You simply tell the `UICollectionView` to move whatever is at a given index path to some other index path. The according method is `moveItem(at:to:)`. This works even if `cellForItem(at:)` would return nil for one of the two index paths. The collection view will ensure the cells are there before they become visible. it does so relying on the data source again, more specifically its `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method. Obviously that means you have to have your data source prepared for the move, i.e. it needs to return the correct cell for the given index. So alter your data source's internal storage (I assume an array?) *before* you move the items in the collection view.

Please see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW7) for more info on that. Also note that this is basically how to move items around programmatically. If you want the user to interactively move them around (in a chat that seems weird to me, though), it gets a little more complicated, but the documentation also helps with that.

Comment: thanks for the throughout explanation, Gero.
I didn't get exactly what you mean by being bad using an UIViewController to user as DataSource and Delegate of an UICollectionView. You mean if I use and UICollectionViewController directly I wouldn't have this kind of issue? I will see how to do it in my case because it is not a matter of updating the data for an specific cell. I also need to rearrange items when needed and I'm not sure about the CollectionView behavior when I try to move an item that is not visible. Well, I'm redoing my code based on your reply anyways, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question. If the currently visible cells on screen are from 50 to 59, the cellForItem at IndexPath 30 will not be available. It would be nil. Reason being the 30the cell would have already been reused to display one of the cells from 50 to 59.

There would not be problem to move cell from 30 to 31. Just update your array/data source and reload the collection view.

Comment: I see, the main issue is that I want to avoid reloading data everytime there is an update on the conversation. What I'm doing here is actually updating the conversation and managing insertion, deletion, move and data update manually like read or unread messages, loading the history of conversations etc.

At moment, I'm redoing my code with an accessory array with the loaded cells, including their indexPaths. So, when I have to update a single message I will use this array.

Comment: you will need not update the cells when they are not visible. Just update the source, next time cellForItem gets called when the cell again become visible, if you have updated your source array, these updates will reflect on collection view cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the cell only if its visible for non visible cell you need to scroll programmatically using `indexpath`:-

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: yourIndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
```

Comment: that's what I thought. unfortunately, I need to go update specific items that are not visible on screen. It's challenging.. redoing my code at moment.